# How can I replace svg from my code?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, svg

let's say I have following code (from standart lightning table example markup)

```
  <div class="slds-icon_container">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default slds-is-sortable__icon">
          <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

in my aura project I want my table cells to interact this way. But I get an error

No COMPONENT named markup://svg found
Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native SVG component support in aura, you have to use a custom SVG Component or use [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/documentation)

```
 <lightning:icon iconName="utility:arrowdown" alternativeText="Arrow Down" />
```